# How to split with multiple symbols and call methods based on the symbol

Tags: java, string

I am making a calculator to test what I can do and I have a small problem. I am trying to take an input parameter on my "input" method and just have them enter their numbers as a string and parse for the doubles on either side of the symbol. However, I am not sure how to do this. I was thinking of using an if statement, something like if (symbol) run method. The code is as follows:

```
public class Calculation_Controls extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

public double A, B;

public String input(String nums){
    String[] split = nums.split("[-.+,/,*,^]");
    int left = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
    int right = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);

}

//What I am trying to invoke for the "if (symbol)"
public double add(double a, double b){
    this.a = A;
    this.b = B;
    return (a + b);
}

public double subtract(double a, double b){
    this.a = A;
    this.b = B;
    return a - b;
}

public double multiply(double a, double b){
    this.a = A;
    this.b = B;
    return a * b;
}

public double divide(double a, double b){
    this.a = A;
    this.b = B;
    return a / b;
}

public double pwr(double a, double b){
    this.A = a;
    this.B = b;
    return (Math.pow(a, b));
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with calling the method based on the symbol using an `if else` or `switch`  statement?

Comment: Better to use a regex than `split`.  `split` is most useful if you don't care what the delimiters are, and you only care what's between them.  That isn't the case here, since you care about the operators.  Also, don't treat `.` as an operator.  The way you have it written, if the user puts in `2.03`, your `split` will treat `.` like an operator, and parse the integers on both sides, giving you 2 and 3.  This isn't what you want.  Leave `.` out of the list of operators, and use `Double.parseDouble`

Comment: @ajb `split` takes a regex, and with that weird regex Jarred uses, it will already jump at the 2 in `2.03`.

Comment: @Robert `split` _takes_ a regex but it doesn't return the delimiters matched by the regex.  I should have said "better to use a `Pattern` and `Matcher`" than `split`, with a regex that is able to return all parts including the operator (delimiter).  That would have been more accurate.

Comment: A. What is the input format ?  B. If you want to select based on the symbol you need to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input format you expect is a string of the general for of "5*6" :

```
public class Calculation_Controls {

    private String[] operators = new String[] {"-","+","/","*","^"};

    public void input(String nums){

        //add: check input is valid 

        String operator = findSymbol(nums);
        if(operator == null ) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
            return;
        }
        String[] split = nums.split(operator);
        int left = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        int right = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        double result = 0;

        switch (operator) {

        case "-":
            result = subtract(left, right);
            break;
        case "+":
            result = add(left, right);
            break;
        case "/":
            result = divide(left, right);
        case "*":
            result = multiply(left, right);
            break;
        case "^":
            result = pwr(left, right);  
            break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid operator");    
        }

    }

    private String findSymbol(String nums) {

        for( String operator : operators) {
            if(nums.contains(operator))
                return operator; 
        }

        return null;
    }

    public double add(double a, double b){
        return (a + b);
    }

    public double subtract(double a, double b){

        return a - b;
    }

    public double multiply(double a, double b){

        return a * b;
    }

    public double divide(double a, double b){

        return a / b;
    }

    public double pwr(double a, double b){

        return (Math.pow(a, b));
    }
}
```

Note: I did not test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case  OR  if  ,

OR by using the interfaces like below .

```
 interface Operation {
        public double resultFor(double left, double right);
    }

class Calculation_Controls extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    public double a, b;
    Map<Character, Operation> operations = new HashMap<Character, Operation>();

    public Calculation_Controls() {
        operations.put('*', new multiply());
        operations.put('-', new subtract());
        operations.put('+', new Add());
        operations.put('/', new divide());
        operations.put('^', new pwr());
    }

    public String input(String nums) {
        String[] split = nums.split("[-.+,/,*,^]");
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("" + split[i].length());
        }
        char operation = nums.charAt(split[0].length());
        int left = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        int right = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        double result = 0;
        Operation op = operations.get(Character.valueOf(operation));
        if (op != null) {
            result = op.resultFor(left, right);
            System.out.println("Result :" + result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Unknown operator");
        }
        return String.valueOf(result);
    }

    class Add implements Operation {
        @Override
        public double resultFor(double left, double right) {
            return (left + right);
        }

    }

    class subtract implements Operation {
        @Override
        public double resultFor(double left, double right) {
            return left - right;
        }

    }

    class divide implements Operation {
        @Override
        public double resultFor(double left, double right) {
            return left / right;
        }

    }

    class multiply implements Operation {
        @Override
        public double resultFor(double left, double right) {
            return left * right;
        }

    }

    class pwr implements Operation {
        @Override
        public double resultFor(double left, double right) {
            return (Math.pow(left, right));
        }

    }
}
```

To use it :

Calculation_Controls inst = new Calculation_Controls();
inst.input("2^4");